# Excel 2010/13 and column grouping : how to have the toggle button on the left?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

When you group columns, there is a toggle button on top to fold/unfold the group.

This button by default appears on the right, which means that when you unfold the group, it jumps. So that you can't just fold and unfold in 2 clicks : you first have to find where the button has jumped

Does anyone know how to put the grouping toggle button on the left, and not on the right as is the default after grouping columns ?

Comment: For all those left to right readers out there !

Answer (score 14, accepted):

1. Go to the Data tab on the ribbion
2. In the Outline section (where you have the Group buttons), click the little button at the bottom right to open the Outline Settings dialog box
3. Uncheck `Summary Columns to the Right of Detail`

*If the settings icon is grayed out, make sure to select a cell that is not inside an excel table.  The menu will then enable, and the check boxes can be hit.  The setting will apply to any groupings you make inside the table.*

Comment: Ah, but this seems to do it for all columns in the sheet rather than just the selected columns. Unless there's something I'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

You could customize your keyboard shortcuts

in Tools + Customize keyborad

Data

Hide details (select your shortcut)

Show details (select your shortcut)

[image]

Comment: I could, but I quite like using the mouse... :)

Comment: @nicolas Then, I do not know the answer.